# CS50 Finance Index. Can't get data to appear in the HTML table

Tags: cs50

I'm working on the index portion of the finance pset. I can't get the stock information to show up in the html table. I'm having a difficult time thinking how to loop through the stock information without having to create a new dictionary with the new data. Could someone help me with this direction that I'm taking? And can someone give me a "better" approach? I feel like this is not the "best" way to solve this problem. Hopefully the code appears correctly, I'm still learning how to use this site.

```
@app.route("/") @login_required def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    #set portfolio GROUPED BY symbol
    portfolio = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares) AS share_total FROM portfolio WHERE user_id = :user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id = session["user_id"])

    row = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])
    remaining_cash = row[0]["cash"]

    total_holding_value = 0
    stock_info = {}

    for stock in portfolio:
        symbol = stock["symbol"]
        shares = stock["share_total"]
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        price = quote["price"]
        holding_value = shares * price
        total_holding_value += holding_value
        stock_info.update({"symbol":symbol, "shares":shares, "price":price, "holding_value":holding_value})

    grand_total = total_holding_value + remaining_cash

    return render_template("index.html", stock_info = stock_info, remaining_cash = remaining_cash, grand_total = grand_total)
```

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Shares</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for stock in stock_info %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ stock.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ stock.shares }}</td>
                <td>{{ stock.price }}</td>
                <td>{{ stock.holding_value }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Remaining Balance:</td>
                <td>{{ remaining_cash }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Grand Total:</td>
                <td>{{ grand_total }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is here `stock_info.update({"symbol":symbol, "shares":shares, "price":price, "holding_value":holding_value})`. From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20update#dict.update) [empashis added].

> update([other])
>
> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, **overwriting existing keys**. Return None.

Chances are you want to send a  *list* of dictionaries to the html. Consider declaring `stock_info` a list, and using the `append` method to add each stock.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now that you say it. It worked with those 2 changes. Is there another way to solve this without making a new dictionary?